# A novel about humans on a water planet who used iron-wings made from a ruined settler ship

Tags: story-identification, space-exploration

Some time ago, I borrowed a book from my father.
It was about a water planet with huge storms and deadly monsters.
There were a few islands where people could live. They moved between islands using iron-wings that they made from the iron of the settler ship used to move humans to the planet and was useless because of some problem when landing (or maybe not, I'm not sure about this last point).
I'm not certain about the characters, but I think there was a young one who wanted to get his wings.

I lost this book some years ago and quickly forgot the title. Today I discovered scifi.stackexchange and I think that maybe you will remember the title or author of this book.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*[Windhaven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windhaven)* by George R. R. Martin and Lisa Tuttle.

> The novel recounts events which occur on the fictional planet Windhaven. Its inhabitants are the descendants of human space voyagers who crash-landed on Windhaven centuries before the events of the book take place. After the crash, the survivors spread out across the many islands of Windhaven's primarily oceanic planetary surface and settled. In order to preserve tenuous lines of communication across vast seas, the stranded population constructed mechanically simplistic gliding rigs from available space-ship wreckage, which could be kept aloft by human pilots almost indefinitely in Windhaven's extremely windy atmosphere. After centuries of using this practice as the principal means of maintaining continuous social contact, Windhaven's "flyers" have developed into a class clearly separate from all others. Additionally, the flyer class maintains ownership of the flying rigs—which are commonly known as "wings"—by keeping them within dynastic flyer families and, therefore, none of Windhaven's people aside from those born into flyer families can legitimately aspire to ever wear them. These class-based differences serve as the impetus for the novel's character-driven narrative.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the wings were not made of iron from ship wreckage. They were made from the remnants of the starship solar sails that fell from space as the wrecked vessel made orbit.  They covered the oceans all around the small archipelago the colonists were forced to call home.